# How do I correctly solve $ \sqrt { x - 6 } - \sqrt { 10 - x } \geq 1 $ ?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$ \sqrt { x - 6 } - \sqrt { 10 - x } \geq 1 $

My solving :

$x$ $\in$ $ [ 6 , 10 ] $ for both the expressions under square root to be valid .

Now

$$ \sqrt {x-6} > \sqrt { 10 - x } $$ since their diff. is positive.

Which means x belongs to [ 8 , 10 ] .

Now

$$ x - 6 + 10 - x -2 \sqrt { -x^2 + 16x -60 } \geq 1 $$

$$ \implies 4x^2 - 64x + 249 \geq 0 $$

$$ \implies x \in [{{16 + \sqrt 7 }\over 2 } , 10 ] $$

**But the answer is**

$$ [{{16 + \sqrt 7 }\over 2} , 0 ] $$

Who is wrong , me or the book ?

Comment: Without looking at your work, the answer given by your book is most likely a typo since the right endpoint of the interval is less than the left endpoint...

Comment: Well as $y=\sqrt { x - 6 } - \sqrt { 10 - x }$ is $2\ge1$ when $x=10$, $x=10$ must be in the solution set.

Comment: Im getting roots as $8\pm 2\sqrt{7}$

Comment: $\sqrt{x-6} \to x \geq 6 ,\sqrt{10-x} \to x \leq 10 \\ 6 \leq x \leq 10 \\$your book maybe has a typo ,remember to type 1 before 0

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I made similar mistake , dont divide by 8 , you have in the numerator 64 + 4 root ( 7 ) , your are dividing by 8 , and cancelling 4 .

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong. One more typo in a textbook !

Answer (score 1):

Another proof that you are correct and that the book is wrong.

Consider the function $$f(x)=\sqrt { x - 6 } - \sqrt { 10 - x }-1$$ which is defined for $6\leq x \leq 10$. Its first derivative being $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x-6}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{10-x}}$$ it is always positive in the interval  .

So, $f(x)$ is increasing and has only one root in the interval (call it $x_*$). For any $x > x_*$ belonging to the interval, the inequality will be satisfied.

You properly found the value of the root.